# Is there any way to monitor the health of my Internet connection?

Tags: networking, internet, ping

Is there a way I can log the health of my Internet connection like pinging a server then making a log/graph where I can see when my Internet connection were down??

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: You would probably be better off enabling ICMP on your router, and then pinging the public IP address from a service like Pingdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a wireless connection you are using you could use something like NetSurveyor. This analyses all traffic, and gives you percentage read outs of the throughput of the Wireless LAN.