# Is there any way to watch my connection health?

Tags: networking, internet-connection

In my Windows 8.1 PC, I never lost the connection. Connection still stood. But the problem is; such as SSH or FTP/SFTP gives me network connection error anmd i have to reconnect them.

Also, my VNC viewer lost the connection and ask me to retry 100 times in a hour.

Fact is, my IP remains same. I never see connection lost icon on windows taskbar. I never see "can't connect' alike error in my browser (all of them). (I have a dynamic IP range from my ISP but not static)

My internet simply works. But such VNC, SSH or SFTP connections lost many times. I am using TV Channel Cable (which came with fiber optic until my apartment). I didn't such problems before.

So, Is there any way to detect this connection waves? Is there any software that i can turn on and log all connection activities?

Note: [Is there any way to monitor the health of my Internet connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/364552/is-there-any-way-to-monitor-the-health-of-my-internet-connection) is not helping.

I am connected via Ethernet.

I hope it was clear.

Comment: Not an answer to fix the problem, but Wireshark can monitor your wired traffic. It can't filter VNC, SSH etc directly but you can filter by the TCP port used. https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Nope. Thats an answer :) I started to capture and save to file. See what will happen until next day. Thanks! (Post as comment so i can accept..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is a free packet analyzer that you can monitor your network traffic and by specifying the TCP ports used for VNC, SSH, FTP etc you should be able to filter packets to help determine the cause of your internet connection.